# How to read file from a non default library location in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a `FolderPicker` where the user is able to choose any folder he like. Then I want to read all files from that folder, which cloud be `D:\foo\bar`.

Since all the sample code I have been able to find reads from some of the default `KnownFolders` I have no clue how to do this. I assume that the user have permissions to read from said folder.

I have started to wonder if this is even possible since I have not found any samples of it.

Does any one have a clue? I am writing in C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701660/winrt-app-to-enumerate-files-outside-libraries-and-known-folders

Comment: I found the way this is supposed to be done, and so I can access it later on as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh972344(v=win.10)

Answer (score 0):

`FolderPicker` returns a `StorageFolder` instance just like any property of `KnownFolders` class. This means you can enumerate the files in it the same way:

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
foreach (var file in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
{
    var contents = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
}
```

The above code reads all the files in the folder as text but you could just as well do anything else.