# Access other Internal Hard drives

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Hello,

**Does anyone know if it is possible to enumerate what internal drives are available on the current Device/PC?**

My app contains the following code:

```
var removableFolders = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
```

When run on Windows 8, this **used to** return any USB devices and SD cards that were connected. Also, I had a second hard drive (mapped as D: drive) which was returned.

**BUT** now it seems that when I run this code on my Windows 8.1 machine, my internal hard drive is no longer included in the result of the `await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()` call.

Perhaps Microsoft tightened up their code with Windows 8.1 and my D: drive is no longer a "RemovableDrive".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you're trying to do? As is, this seems to be answered by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701660/winrt-app-to-enumerate-files-outside-libraries-and-known-folders). I'm surprised that the API for `RemovableDevices` returned your `D` drive in Win 8. I wouldn't have expected that (as it is an internal drive you mentioned). Could you add what you're trying to do?

Comment: Essentially, I want to download and save files to a second hard drive. The app has the potential to download a giant library of files and some people may have a second hard drive for just such a massive library. It works with SD cards, USB drives, and (up until 8.1) my 2nd hard drive. It was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment...

So you want to determine if there is a second drive available, is that it?  Are you familiar with the System.IO.DriveInfo class?

```
        foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", di.Name, di.DriveType));
        }
```

Comment: System.IO.DriveInfo is not available for WinRT. Otherwise this would be perfect. Maybe I'm mistaken (I hope so), but I haven't been able to use this.